# In C getting error: initializer element is not constant

Tags: arrays, c

I want to use very large array and for this I tried to create an array dynamically on the heap. But getting this error. Please, help me to run this or suggest me a better way to work with large arrays in c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

long long *arr = (long long*)malloc(1000000001 * sizeof(long long));

void some_function(long long *arr,long long n)
{
    //
    //
    //
}


int main()
{
    long long n=1000000000;
    
    for(long long i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%ld",arr[i]);
    }
    
    some_function(arr,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't call functions outside of a scope of some other function. That is your `malloc` should be inside of some function.

Comment: ....and hope you're building and x64 target, otherwise this isn't going to work regardless, even if you do move the allocation within a function and fix the mismatching format specifiers you're using.